# DBCheckBox все время не активный

Tags: база-данных, delphi, null, компоненты, связь

Столкнулась с такой проблемой: при добавлении нового `DBCheckBox` он все время не активный.

В инспекторе объектов указаны следующие свойства:

- `AllowGrayed` установлен в `False`
- `DataSource` указан
- `DataField` указан
- `ValueChecked` True
- `ValueUnchecked` False
- `ReadOnly` False
- Алиас БД указан

Связь с БД происходит с помощью таких компонентов:

- `TDatabase` подключение стоит в `true`, название и алис БД так же
  указан.
- `TTable`, `DataSource`
- `MasterSource` заполнен
- название БД так же указано
- название таблицы в `TableName` так же есть

Программу не могу скинуть слишком большая. Могу добавить скрины инспектора объектов.

`DBCheckBox` должен добавлять 1 в таблицу при нажатии, пока там значения `null`, еще ни разу туда не добавляли информацию, тип поля в БД `integer`.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. "добавлять" или "изменять"?

Comment: где-то у Вас не хватает `table.Append();`

Comment: Должен добавлять 1 в определенное поле бд

Comment: "добавлять" или "изменять"?

Comment: А можно немного подробней про table.Append();